# Invalid Object Name for Table which is successfully updated in the same Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, invalid-object-name

We are seeing 'interesting behavior with our SQL Sever Database. We have a merge statement which selects a table X. In the match clauses there is a subselect to table X. When we execute the stored procedure from the SQL Server Tools it works fine. But when executed from IPC (an ETL Tool) we get an exception `Invalid object name 'X'.`

So far nothing special as I understand there can get lots of things wrong with permissions and stuff.

The strange thing: The merge statement is in a try block and in the catch block the error message gets written into the table X via an update statement! How is this possible when Sql Server complains it can't find a table X?

Also everything works fine with another stored procedure which is constructed in the same way (via code generation) but on a different set of tables.

The code looks like this

```
    merge ...
    using
    (select ...
    from dbo.X
    where ...
    when not matched by target 
    and not exists (select 1 from dbo.X q2 where ...)
    then insert (...
    )
    values (...
    )
    when matched and q.ACTION='D'
    then delete
    when matched AND NOT exists (select 1 from dbo.X q3 where ...)
    then update 
    set
      ...

    OUTPUT $action INTO @l_SummaryOfChanges;
    -- Query the results of the table variable.
    SELECT ACTION, COUNT(*) AS CountPerChange
    FROM @l_SummaryOfChanges
    GROUP BY ACTION;
  end try
  begin catch
    update dbo.X
    set LAST_ERROR_MSG=ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_COUNTER=ERROR_COUNTER+1
    where SYNC_ID=@l_SyncID
  end catch
```

Any ideas what is going on?Invalid object name 'sync$_tabTeiledaten'.

Comment: Is that the exact message please? And all uses of X are schema qualified with dbo?

Comment: I updated the error message to match exactly what we see. All occurences in the code a prefixed by dbo. The capitalization is exactly the same in all occurences. But differs from what we see in the error message. (That might be a hint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found it. gbn's question triggered the realization that the usage of X had nothing to do with the exception. In fact on target table of the merge was a trigger which is referencing X but from a different schema without actually specifying the schema.

May somebody will benefit from the way we debugged this shit:

- we duplicated X with a new name (Y) and still got the error message saying 'Invalid object name 'X'. At that point we thought we might reference a view or something so ..
- we removed all the columns (there where lots of) from the merge statement, except those which where necessary due to Not Null Constraints. The problem persisted
- We removed 1 of the branches of the merge statement at a time. The problem persisted.
- we removed the complete merge statement. The error was gone. At that point we realized that something fishy might go on with the target table.
- On inspection we found the trigger from hell.